# Is there any way to put a default argument? xc8

Tags: c, xc8

I have this simple lcd xc8 header file:

```
#ifndef XC_PANTALLACWS_H
#define XC_PANTALLACWS_H

#include "lcd.h"

void pantallaCWS (const char stringProyecto){
    const char stringProyecto[16] = "__proyNombre____";
    Lcd_Init();
    Lcd_Out(1, 0, stringProyecto);
}

#endif
```

What I would like to do is that, if an argument is not given in the function, put one by default.

is this possible?

Comment: never put executable code in a header file

Comment: And the answer to the question is : No, not in C

Comment: "never put executable code in a header file" - that's not completely correct @Mike - think of `static`/`inline` functions, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think there is an error in your argument declaration as it is only one char but you want a string.

Then the trick is to check for a null argument, and if so, provide your default argument in the function, for example:

```
void pantallaCWS (const char *stringProyecto){
    const char *myString;
    if (stringProyecto==0)
        myString= "__proyNombre____";
    else
        myString= stringProyecto;
    Lcd_Init();
    Lcd_Out(1, 0, myString);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this matches the requirement: *"if an argument is not given in the function"*

Comment: This work for me.  I´ll call the function in two ways: 1: pantallaCWS (null) or 2: pantallaCWS (anyString)   ..... thanksss

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, the alternative solution is to work with varargs, but I don't think the OP is up to that. (Besides, his declaration doesn't allow it.)